# Sistema de telas pelo console (python)

Tags: python

Estou desenvolvendo um RPG baseado em texto (ainda sou muito iniciante e estou aplicando meus aprendizados nesse joguinho), e gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de criar 'displays' dentro do próprio console, assim como no pygame, se o jogador está no menu principal e quer ir para a tela de opções, ele escreve o comando 'opções', a tela (console) limpa completamente e mostra apenas a tela de opções, e assim será para todas as funções, outro exemplo, o jogador quer acessar o inventário durante o jogo, então ele escreve 'inventario', o console fica completamente vazio e então mostra o inventario. Da maneira que está meu codigo, as coisas acontecem de maneira sucessiva, como sempre no console, segue meu codigo.

EXEMPLO:

```
def main_menu():
    print('Jogar')
    escolha = str(input(''))
    if escolha in 'jogar':
        jogo()


def jogo():
    print('Você está no jogo')

main_menu()
```

O Programa inicia no maine_menu(), ao digitar 'Jogar', o programa encaminha o jogador ao jogo (**jogo()**).
Porém, quando o jogo() é chamado, o que está acima ainda é visivel (**main_menu()**), eu gostaria que, quando o usuario digitasse a palavra 'Jogar', a tela fosse limpa e aparecesse apenas a mensagem "Você está no jogo"

Comment: Rodrigo, pelo o que está descrevendo a resposta citada atenderá completamente sua necessidade. Se não funcionou, talvez tenha executado errado; ou a sua necessidade é diferente da que descreveu na pergunta. Independente de qual for, nos falta informações para prosseguir, então recomendo que, se considerar que a resposta citada não te atende, edite a pergunta e elabore um [mcve] demonstrando o problema.

Comment: Rodrigo, acho que você não leu o link sobre [mcve], então peço que leia (ou releia). Um código completo (e enorme) não nos ajuda em nada reproduzir o problema, principalmente quando não está completo por ser muito grande. O termo "Mínimo" remete justamente ao fato que você deve reduzir o escopo do problema até o ponto onde está o erro, eliminando tudo que é ruído e sem relação com o problema.

Comment: Aproveitando, recomendo que leia o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/5878).

Comment: Se você quiser realmente fazer essa aplicação no terminal, vale a pena dar  uma olhada na biblitoeca ncurses da biblioteca padrão - https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html - para windows: https://pypi.org/project/windows-curses/

Comment: Essa questão tem espaço paa ser expandida com sugestões de interface, e bibliotecas para serem usadas no console e isso vai _muito_ além de "apagar a tela".

Comment: usa QT pra criar janelas

Answer (score 4):

Zérima coisa - você tem que avaliar se quer realmente fazer uma aplicação maior com console, só com input e print, ou quer criar algo com uma interface mais familiar para usuários - seja com Tkinter (ou Qt, GTK, Kivy), Pygame ou Web.  Mas como existe toda uma categoria de jogos "vintage" que são os "adventures de texto" - essa decisão pode fazer bem mais sentido para o que você quer, do que se fosse um app de "agenda" ou qualquer outra coisa que as pessoas costumam codar pra aprender.

Primeira coisa - no limite da simplicidade, toda a tela que o jogador vai entrar vai simplesmente imprimir todo o conteúdo novo - nesse caso, você só precisa, no inicio de cada função que representa um "comodo", colocar o código para apagar a tela.

Para apagar a tela, o mais simples é só imprimir um número de linhas em branco igual ou maior do que o número de linhas no terminal -então, é só imprimir um "\n"- o caractere de 'nova linha' multiplicado por um valor maior do que o número de linhas no terminal. Um valor de 130 vai dar conta mesmo de um terminal em uma tela 4K com uma fonte pequena, então `print("\n" * 130)` .

A resposta encontrada em vários lugares de chamar `os.system("cls")` ou `os.system("clear")` (dependendo do sistema ) é ruim em geral, por que o custo de um processo externo só pra apagar a tela dá um sobressalto no coração de quem olhar seu código. (Na prática, em uma aplicação single-user no console, a performance disso não faz diferença, no entanto).

Segunda coisa - se quiser fazer algo sofisticado no termial, além de apagar a tela, é legal poder imprimir texto colorido, posicionar o cursor, usar informação em janelas, etc... 
A solução padrão para isso mais direta, sem usar bibliotecas terceiras, é usar os ANSI Codes - sequências especiais de impressão, começando com o caracter especial "ESC" (código 0x1B) que podem alterar a cor, posicionar o cursor, etc... https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_escape_ANSI

O problema é que isso não funciona  no windows diretamente sem umas configurações cabulosas no registry - a solução é usar a biblioteca terceira "colorama" https://pypi.org/project/colorama/

Terceiro: Se quiser coisas mais sofisticadas - como ter janelinhas (imagine em todas as telas ter em um canto, uma moldura onde você poe as stats do personagem e o inventorio, por exemplo), você pode usar a biblioteca "curses" que vem com o Python. https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html

De novo, por conta da falat de atenção que a microsoft deu para o terminal de 1985 até 2019, o windows requer configurações adicionais para usar o curses: 
 https://pypi.org/project/windows-curses/   (está prometido um terminal do nível que os desenvolvedores precisam em alguma atualização do Windows 10 para esse ano)

Quarto: E, por fim, se quiser realmente efeitos interessantes, de coisas poderem se mover na tela do terminal, e formas geométricas como é possível no pygame, há o projeto "terminedia" (de minha autoria)  - o suporte a WIndows e preliminar, e fica bem lento e ainda não funcionam cores - mas no terminal do Linux é possível chegar a uns efeitos bem interessantes. Por enquanto é necessário instalar a partir do branch master, e explorar os programas de exemplo que vem junto: https://github.com/jsbueno/terminedia
(para instalar a partir do master usando o pip, basta digitar:
`pip install git+https://github.com/jsbueno/terminedia.git`)